# When exactly does Hibernate create tables according to @Entity mappings?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ddl

I have a test class that fetches a JWT token in its constructor. Or rather, it *tries to*: the tables are not yet created by the time constructor code is executed so all test methods fail with a 401 error

```java
// a snippet from my test class
public class UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest extends IntegrationTestContext {
    private static final String testUsername = "mickey_m";
    private static final String testPassword = "mickey";
    private final String token;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "/api/v1/user/question-comments/";
    private static final String BASE_SCRIPT_PATH = "/sql/UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest/";
    private ExpectationTester expectationTester;

    @Autowired
    public UserQuestionCommentRestControllerTest(TestUtil testUtil) throws Exception {
        token = testUtil.getToken(testUsername, testPassword);
    }
    @Test
    @Sql(executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "GetCommentTest/before.sql") // e.g. attempts to insert into the security join table accounts_permissions
    @Sql(executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD, value = BASE_SCRIPT_PATH + "GetCommentTest/after.sql")
    public void getCommentTest() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URI + 1)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse();
    // asserts
```

```java
// here's what getToken() does
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TestUtil {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final MockMvc mockMvc;

    public String getToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/token")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new JwtRequestDto(username, password))))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
        ObjectNode content = objectMapper.readValue(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(), ObjectNode.class);
        return "Bearer " + objectMapper.readValue(content.get("data").toString(), String.class);
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

```java
// a snippet from the Account @Entity class
    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "accounts_permissions", // ← here it is
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", nullable = false),
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"account_id", "permission_id"}))
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
```

It made me wonder: **when exactly does schema initialization happen when your `ddl-auto` is set to some value involving automatic table creation** (like `create`, as in my code)? I thought it happens once your `@Entity` classes are loaded in memory, but it appears it is not the case